# Why does hadoop sort the input of the reducers?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I compared time performance of the following two reducers for the Word Count problem. These reducers differ by whether they take advantage of their input being sorted on key.

Reducer 1 (does not make use of input being sorted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# maps words to their counts
word2count = {}

for line in sys.stdin:
    w = line.strip().split()[0] # this is the word
    word2count[w] = (word2count[w] + 1 if word2count.has_key(w) 
                     else 1)

# Write (unsorted) tuples to stdout
for word in word2count.keys():
    print '%s\t%s' % (word, word2count[word])
```

Reducer 2 (makes use of input being sorted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys

# maps words to their counts
word2count = {}
last = ""
count = 0

for line in sys.stdin:
    w = line.strip().split()[0] # this is the word
    if w != last and count != 0:
        word2count[last] = count
        last = w
        count = 1
    else: count += 1
if last != "": word2count[last] = count

# Write (unsorted) tuples to stdout
for word in word2count.keys():
    print '%s\t%s' % (word, word2count[word])
```

The same mapper was used with both reducers:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import string

#--- get all lines from stdin ---
for line in sys.stdin:
    #--- to lower case and remove punctuation ---
    line = line.lower().translate(None, string.punctuation)

    #--- split the line into words ---
    words = line.split()

    #--- output tuples [word, 1] in tab-delimited format---
    for word in words: 
        print '%s\t%s' % (word, "1")
```

I used [the English translation of "War and Peace"](http://www.gutenberg.org/files/2600/2600-0.txt) as input. The difference in time performance (CPU time) of the reducers was about 20%.

Here is the command line I used to measure time:

```
./mapper.py < war_and_peace.txt | sort | time ./reducer.py > /dev/null
```

Given that the first reducer is much simpler and that sorting the input of reducers takes time (which probably eats up those 20%), my question is: why does hadoop sort **the input of reducers**? are there problems for which the input of the reducers being sorted is more significant than in Word Count? (**Please note:** I realize that the output of each mapper needs to be sorted in order to balance the load of the reducers. My question is about the motivation for merging the key-value pairs coming from the different mappers instead of simply appending them.)

Comment: I do not agree that this question is a duplicate. Please see my answer, which points out the difficulty that was not dealt with (unless I am missing something) in the quoted post.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer that I think is correct (unless people who marked this question as duplicate can point me to this answer in the post they found, they should be ashamed). The question ignored the memory aspect. Storing the keys in the dictionary assumes that all the keys can fit in memory, which in general may not be the case. Sorting of the reducers' output by key allows working with only one key at a time.